# Sourcing scripts with a for loop for different variables

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I have several shell scripts that I summarised within a global script. I am using some variables that are the same across all scripts, and I wrote a separate script for this, which I am sourcing in each sub-script.
This is what my variables script looks like:

```
variables.sh
NUMBER="6"
TYPE="${NUMBER}_xyz"
STATE="S05"
DIR="path/file_${NUMBER}_blabla"
FILE="file.txt"
```

My global script, global.sh, looks like this:

```
source variables.sh
bash script1.sh
bash script2.sh
...
```

Now, I need to change the NUMBER variable in my variables script, run the global script, change the number, run the global script again etc. for each number from 6-15. At the moment I am doing this manually every time the global script has finished, but it's taking up a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to adapt `variables.sh` so that `NUMBER` is not set unconditionally any more:

```
NUMBER=${NUMBER:-6}
```

That allows you to pass the value from the calling process:

```
for((NUMBER=6;NUMBER<16;NUMBER++)); do
  source variables.sh
  bash script1.sh
  bash script2.sh
done
```

General remark: I am surprised that this works without `export` statements or `set -a`.

Comment: My script is indeed executed 10 times now, but the problem is, it inputs the number 6 for the variable every time, not numbers from 6-15.

Comment: @Kaly You have modified `variables.sh` as I told you?

Comment: Yep, I placed NUMBER=${NUMBER:-6} into my script, and also replaced the other "NUMBER"s inside variables.sh with ${NUMBER:-6}. Maybe that was wrong?

Comment: @Kaly You should replace only the `NUMBER=` line. It shouldn't cause problems in the other positions, though. For debugging put a line `echo $NUMBER` at the beginning of `variables.sh`.

Comment: Sorry about that! It still didn't work, but I placed an "export" before "NUMBER=" and now it works perfectly. Thanks so much!